# How to find a formula relating three values?

Tags: extrapolation

I haven't studied maths since high-school (20 years ago) and would like to find a formula to relate these values:

```
 x     y      z
-----|------|-------  
   1 | 0.25 | 0.25
   2 | 0.25 | 0.625
   3 | 0.25 | 0.75
   4 | 0.25 | 0.8125
   5 | 0.25 | 0.85

 1.5 | 0.25 | 0.5
  10 | 0.25 | 0.925
   2 | 0.1  | 0.55
```

The formula would find *z* from known *x* and *y* values.

e.g. if *x = 6* and *y = 0.25* what is *z*?

Thanks for any help solving the problem or pointing me in the right direction. I can try to explain the context if that helps, but perhaps it's easier just to work with the numbers.

Comment: There are infinitely many formulas that fit the given numbers but give widely different answers for $x=6$, $y=.25$. You have to know more about what kind of function you are trying to fit, in order to give a useful answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the help. How might I better define the kind of function I am looking for? I can't even find one formula that fits. Visually I understand the problem and could try to describe it in those terms or I can also supply more results from the model I have. I'm looking for the simpliest solution that gives the same results as the model.

Comment: OK, here's one way, but it probably doesn't give you what you want. Temporarily ignore that last data point. Then all your data points have the same $y$-value, so you can ignore $y$ and get a polynomial $p(x)$ that fits all the points by using Lagrange interpolation (look it up!). Then you can find a number $c$ such that $p(x)+c(y-.25)$ fits all your points.

Comment: Hi Gerry, thanks for trying me on that. To be honest I don't know what a polynomial is and having tried to read up on Lagrange Interpolation I'm struggling to find anything I can understand... I'll keep trying

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks again. I'm clearer on _polynomials_ now. Still not sure how to go about interpolation. In your example you show _c(y – .25)_ but _y_ is _.25_ so that will be zero. I'm confused.

Comment: That's the point. That term vanishes when $y=.25$, but not for that other point you have, the one with $y=.1$. You adjust $c$ to make the formula fit at that one extra point. But, honestly: if you don't know what a polynomial is, you are several years of study away from being able to tackle the problem you have set yourself, or from being able to understand a serious discussion of it. You may as well ask how to cure cancer, when you don't know what a cell is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks again. The explaination about _c(y – .25)_ makes perfect sense. Perhaps this is out of my league but I have to start somewhere and I'm learning a lot so far. Perhaps I understand a _polynomial_ without being familiar with the terminonolgy. So yes, _p(x)_ still doesn't make sense to me. Are we multiplying _x_ by _p_? What is _p_?

Comment: $p$ is the name of the polynomial you get by applying Lagrange interpolation. It is a function of the variable $x$. You are not familiar with function notation? This is going to be even harder than I thought.

Comment: @gerry I found a formula that works by visualising the problem and naming components of the formula. Still don't know how to do this another way. $1 =$ size of A-type step relative to overlap of A-type steps = size of B-type step relative to overlap of B-type steps. $x =$ size ratio between A-type and B-type steps. $y =$ relative overlap of A-type steps. $1-y =$ distance between centres of A-type steps. $(1-y)/x =$ distance between centres of B-type steps. $z = (1-(1-y)/x) =$ relative overlap of B-type steps that ensures distance between centres of all B-type and A-type steps is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome back to maths. I hope the the re-introduction will not be too fearful!

Visualizing 3-dimensional data is **very** hard.

Whenever possible, try to start with the simplest model possible to describe your situation and build upwards. Thus, as Gerry suggested, given that for all but one data point, the y-value is constant, consider the scenario if you temporarily ignore it and consider this a 2-dimensional question.

In this case, graphing $x$ versus $z$ on graph paper or via Excel should always be your first step.

In my experience as a mathematician and statistician, I always find it useful to mentally think what do I expect the answer to be, **before** I plug my data into any formulae or models.

Once you do this you will immediately realize how much your point $x=10, z=0.925$ is separated from all your other data points.

The second thing to notice is that if you ignore this point, too, then a line fits the rest of your data quite well. Using something like Excel, with its built-in capabilities of line-of-best-fit, you would get something like $z=0.15x+0.22$. This would give value of $z=1.12$ if $x=6$.

However, you will notice that the if you include that far-right point, the data does not really look like a straight line at all, but rather a curve (maybe a logarithmic graph). In this case you would probably get a $z$ vaue of $\simeq 0.9$ if $x=6$.

This is where you have to balance up two questions:

1. Based on how I collected my data, would I expect to be a simple linear relationship or a more complex curve? If so, would I expect it to curve upwards or downwards.
   Other questions like the following may also help: "Do i expect the line-of-best fit to go through the origin?", "Can we have negative $x$ values, and/or negative $z$ values?, "What might I expect for very large $x$?"
2. How much confidence do I have that the point x=10, which lies much further away than the other points, is correct? Can we obtain more data in between $x=5$ and $x=10$ to strengthen our confidence?

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the help. Okay, keeping things two dimensional, I would expect the line to be a curve with _z_ tending towards _1_ as _x_ increases. 

_x_ can't be negative but it could be less than _1_ which would lead to a negative value of _z_

Comment: For a very large _x_ I'd expect a value very close to _1_.

Comment: when x = 6, z = 0.875